# Gsub to identify string before first whitespace, only numbers

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Just as the title says,

Here's some data

```
DF<- data.frame(StreetName=c("PO BOX 850", "555 Happy Lane"))
```

Here's my code

```
DF$StreetName <- sub(".*? (.+)", "\\1", DF$StreetName)
```

And I also tried this

```
DF$StreetName<- sub("\\d? (.+)", "\\1", DF$StreetName)
```

But both are killing my PO BOX addys.

What I need is

```
   StreetName
    PO BOX 850
    Happy Lane
```

Comment: Maybe `sub("^\\d+\\s*", "",  DF$StreetName)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
val1 <- c("PO BOX 850", "555 Happy Lane")
val1
sub("^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+","",val1)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "PO BOX 850" "Happy Lane"
```

This is implemented to a vector as an example you could use it for data frame's values too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
sub("^\\d+\\s*", "", DF$StreetName)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces.

Note that in case you want to only match the digits and at least 1 whitespace, you need to replace `*` with `+`.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/c21eer/1).

```
> DF<- data.frame(StreetName=c("PO BOX 850", "555 Happy Lane"))
> sub("^\\d+\\s*", "", DF$StreetName)
[1] "PO BOX 850" "Happy Lane"
```